# Get all related set objects on Django object including those not yet persisted to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Let's say I have the following simple Django models:

```
class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And I create the following objects:

```
club1 = Club.objects.create(name="Club1")
student1 = Student.objects.create(name="Student1", club=club1)
print(club1.student_set.all())
# <QuerySet [<Student: Student1>]>
```

Now I'm going to instantiate a second student object on the club object but NOT YET persist it to the database. Is there any way to get all students associated with `club1` BEFORE it has been written to the DB? Looks like using the standard approach just returns the objects stored in the DB:

```
student2 = Student(name="Student2", club=club1)
print(club1.student_set.all())
# <QuerySet [<Student: Student1>]>

# Goal is to get this:
# <QuerySet [<Student: Student1>, <Student: Student2>]>
```

The reason I need this is to perform some validation of the staged data state.

Comment: It's impossible as `club1.student_set.all()` makes a query into database and it won't return you a line which doesn't exist here yet. Could you explain what type of validation you want to have in your question, maybe there is another better solution for you.

Comment: @SergeyPugach a club can only have 3 students so I want to validate the length of the staged list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform validation of the student added, you should use the signal that gets triggered on the save. If you raise an error in the validation, the save does not get performed.

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

m2m_changed.connect(student_set_changed, sender=Club.student_set.through) 

def student_set_changed(*args, **kwargs):
    # Do you validation
    return
```

More on how to handle Many2Many field changes in [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#m2m-changed)

Comment: This doesn't work because I'm not dealing with ManyToMany, only ManyToOne.

Comment: Oh, my bad, just override the save then -> refer to Sergey below

Answer (score 0):

You can add `related_name` attr in order to have easy access to all club's students. And you can validate students' quantity before saving it.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    club = models.ForeignKey(
        Club, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True,
        related_name='students', # add this related name and run migratioin
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def validate_club_students(self):
        if self.club.students.count() >= 3:
            raise ValidationError('The club already has 3 students!')

    def save(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        self.validate_club_students()
        super().save(*arg, **kwargs)
```

It means that before saving a new student for a certain club you can check how many students does the club have.